# Flat, non-faithfully flat, submodule of a faithfully flat module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, flatness

Let $R$ be a unital ring (not necessarily commutative) and let $M$ be a (left) faithfully flat module over $R$. Can there exist a non-zero
flat (left) $R$-submodule of $M$ that is not faithfully flat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be any faithfully flat module and $B$ be any flat module that is not faithfully flat.  Then $M=A\oplus B$ is faithfully flat and contains $B$ as a submodule.